# jwt.auth laravel 5.2 package token is not working with my ip address

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2.And for authentication I am using "jwt.auth" package to generate JSON web tokens.

I started the server

```
php artisan serve
```

Now,

I'll send a get request to my server to the url:

```
localhost:8000/api/v1/company
```

and I pass Authorization: Bearer {token} in header.

I get response.

Now I do the same thing with my ip address(as we are working in LAN):

```
http://10.0.1.65/project/public/api/v1/company
```

and I pass Authorization: Bearer {token} in header.
This is returning me {"error":"token_not_provided"}

The controllers that aren't using the jwt.auth is working fine.But the one using is returning this.

I don't have any idea of what's happening inside.

How come this happen?Working for localhost but not working with my IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectified the problem.

The reason why that was not working is,In laravel 5.2 by default the header,
Authorization : Bearer {token} will not be accepted for "CORS" requests.

This was the main reason why this isn't working.So,we need to add following code to our /public/.httaccess .This code tells the server to accept authorization headers when it is cross domain access.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```